# After write the rule, every page is redirected to the error page

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, umbraco, rules, umbraco8

I wrote a rule for redirect non-www to www. Now my site goes to http://www.abcd.com.tr www came and that's what I wanted, but whichever page I click on I get to the error page.

My rule code is below;

```
 <rule name="Add WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

For example when I click this link http://www.abcd.com.tr/tr-tr/deneme/test/ page redirect to error page. Also when I use site without www, there was no problem, all page was working.

Answer (score 0):

Please see what I do for one of my projects, with this you are always redirected to a `https://www` URL.

PS: I have updated the pattern to include your domain name, please update the "pattern" setting for your project and delete the unnecessary bits.

```
 <rule name="Redirect all domain bar azure and actual domain" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.abcd\.com\.tr|abcd\-live\-fe\-staging\.azurewebsites\.net" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.abcd.com.tr/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<rule name="Redirect NONWWW to WWW " stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.azurewebsites.net$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.azurewebsites.nyc/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```